# How to figure out which methods IDynamicMemberReferenceOperation refers to?

Tags: dynamic, roslyn

I have the following function in my `OperationWalker`:

```
public override void VisitDynamicInvocation(IDynamicInvocationOperation operation)
{
    var memberReferenceOp = (IDynamicMemberReferenceOperation)operation.Operation;
    switch (memberReferenceOp.Instance.Type)
    {
        case INamedTypeSymbol type:
            {
                var memberName = memberReferenceOp.MemberName;
                var members = type.GetMembers(memberName);
                if (members.Length > 1)
                {
                    // WHAT DO I DO HERE ???
                }
                else
                {
                    Result.Add((IMethodSymbol)members[0]);
                }
                break;
            }

        case IDynamicTypeSymbol dynamicType:
            Unresolved.Add((operation.Syntax, memberReferenceOp.MemberName));
            break;
    }
}
```

I am clueless when a method on a normal type (non dynamic) is called with a dynamic parameter and there is a choice of target methods with the same name. E.g.:

```
class A
{
    public void Get(int i){}
    public void Get(string s){}
    public void Get(object o){}
    public void Get(double s, int precision){}
}
...
dynamic x = ...;
A a;
a.Get(x)
```

In this case any of the first 3 `A.Get` methods may be called, depending on the actual type of `x`. But not the fourth method.

Is there a way in Roslyn to get this information? Specifically in this example, I would like to get the symbols for first 3 `Get` methods.

The logic is non trivial, because one needs to take into account:

1. Default parameters, so just counting the arguments may not be enough
2. Type conversions
3. Visibility Scope
4. Number of arguments
5. Parameters may be passed using the named syntax in arbitrary order

Combining it all together we get non trivial logic. Is there anything in the `SemanticModel` or anywhere else to help get the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and it is straightforward - `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo`. When there is exact match its `Symbol` property returns it. When there are multiple candidates, as may be the case when one of the passed arguments is `dynamic`, then the property `CandidateSymbols` holds all the options.

I have not tested it with extension methods, so it is possible there is a gap there.